# How do I delete LEFT JOIN rows that are NULL in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I am doing a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT mt_order_delivery_address.id, 
       mt_order.order_id, 
       mt_order_delivery_address.client_id
FROM mt_order_delivery_address
LEFT JOIN mt_order ON mt_order.order_id = mt_order_delivery_address.order_id
```

which then gives me a list like:

```
id     order_id    client_id
----------------------------
1032   NULL        382
1028   NULL        282
1020   784344      920
1002   232496      490
```

I want to get rid of the rows in `mt_order_delivery_address` where there is no corresponding `order_id` in `mt_order`. How would I do this? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

UPDATE:

I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

`DELETE mt_order_delivery_address.id
FROM mt_order_delivery_address
LEFT JOIN mt_order ON mt_order.order_id = mt_order_delivery_address.order_id
WHERE mt_order.order_id IS NULL`

Comment: Select `id` only and add `WHERE mt_order.order_id IS NULL`, then use this as a sub-query for DELETE like `WHERE id IN ([subquery here])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "delete" you mean "don't show them in this query result" you can use an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. It's worth learning the different types of joins and how to use them.

If by "delete" you mean "`DELETE` the rows in my_order_delivery_address that have no matching my_order", you can do a [multi-table DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE a FROM mt_order_delivery_address AS a
LEFT JOIN mt_order AS o USING (order_id)
WHERE o.order_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for explaining it and taking the time :)